# "J2OBJC_HOME\ not\ correctly\ defined\ in\ Settings.xcconfig

Tags: java, objective-c, j2objc

Guys last 2 to 3 day I am trying to run an example project for `J2OBJC` conversion. First I faced issue for the `j2objc` command not found, fixed this issue by adding the path to the /etc/paths file. Now I am facing an issue like `J2OBJC_HOME` path not defined correctly.

`/bin/sh -c if\ [\ !\ -f\ \"${J2OBJC_HOME}/j2objc\"\ ];\ then\ echo\ \"J2OBJC_HOME\ not\ correctly\ defined\ in\ Settings.xcconfig,\ currently\ set\ to\ \'${J2OBJC_HOME}\'\";\ exit\ 1;\ fi;\
\"${J2OBJC_HOME}/j2objc\"\ -d\ ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}\ -sourcepath\ \"${PROJECT_DIR}/Classes\"\ --no-package-directories\ -use-arc\ --prefix\ Othello.Engine=JOE\ -g\ ${INPUT_FILE_PATH};

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.JavacEnvironment (file:/Users/*****/Documents/j2objc-2.0.5/lib/j2objc.jar) to field com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.java_base
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.JavacEnvironment
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
error: internal error translating "/Users/*****/Downloads/j2objc-sample-reversi-master/Classes/Othello/Engine/Score.java"
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: operator
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertBinary(TreeConverter.java:513)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:346)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertArrayAccess(TreeConverter.java:476)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:230)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertAssignment(TreeConverter.java:497)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:236)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertExpressionStatement(TreeConverter.java:691)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:263)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertBlock(TreeConverter.java:543)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:238)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertMethodDeclaration(TreeConverter.java:888)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:283)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertAbstractTypeDeclaration(TreeConverter.java:390)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertClassDeclaration(TreeConverter.java:603)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertInner(TreeConverter.java:246)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convert(TreeConverter.java:202)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.TreeConverter.convertCompilationUnit(TreeConverter.java:173)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.JavacParser.parseFiles(JavacParser.java:173)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.FileProcessor.processBatch(FileProcessor.java:141)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.FileProcessor.processInputs(FileProcessor.java:70)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.TranslationProcessor.processInputs(TranslationProcessor.java:78)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.J2ObjC.run(J2ObjC.java:127)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.J2ObjC.main(J2ObjC.java:177)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.javac.JavacParser.parseFiles(JavacParser.java:175)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.FileProcessor.processBatch(FileProcessor.java:141)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.FileProcessor.processInputs(FileProcessor.java:70)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.pipeline.TranslationProcessor.processInputs(TranslationProcessor.java:78)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.J2ObjC.run(J2ObjC.java:127)
    at com.google.devtools.j2objc.J2ObjC.main(J2ObjC.java:177)`

Guys, please help me to fix the above, anyone already faces such issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most "*_HOME" settings, it's something you need to specify (like JAVA_HOME, KOTLIN_HOME, GROOVY_HOME, etc.). Edit Settings.xconfig and set J2OBJC_HOME to the same path you added to /etc/paths.

The next problem is that j2objc does not run with a Java 9 JDK (coming soon). The good news is that multiple JDKs can be installed on your Mac, and the j2objc script will pick the latest Java 8 JDK installed, regardless of whether the Java 9 JDK is the default. Go to [Oracle's Java SE Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/index.html), get the latest Java 8 JDK and install it.

Comment: Thanks, @tball. I was fed up to build the J2OBJC example game with JDK-9.  On the site https://developers.google.com/j2objc/ 
Requirements
JDK 1.8 or higher
Mac workstation or laptop
Mac OS X 10.11 or higher
Xcode 7 or higher

That is why I tried with JDK-9. Now I am really happy to say thank you. You saved another week without losing a day. Now I can able to build the example project with JDK 1.8 v.

I am continuing my work on J2OBJC integration with BLE communication code base. Will meet you again with new doubts.